# Chart Integration in YII Framework

Tags: yii

Is there any way by which we can show the grid column data in a chart  in YII framework? How can I fetch data from database based upon a query and show it in a chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from database with use of YII functions. Pass data to JS chart function as json array.

Highcahrt extension available for yii in below link.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-highcharts-widget/

Other charts widely used with YII:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-chartjs/

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/googlechart/

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eamchartwidget/